# Nuxt.js server side rendering not getting cookie on refresh

Tags: authentication, cookies, nuxt.js

I log in with cookies in Nuxt js. Everything works normally locally. But there is a problem placing it on the server. The problem is that after I log in, everything works, but when I refresh the page, it cannot read the cookies and the page does not work. I have used many cookie libraries in Nuxt js but it still gives the same error.. The codes are as follows. (Store)

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies(null,{ path: '/' });

export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    token: cookies.get('token'),
    user: {},
    publicUserData: {},
    userName: {},
  },
  getters: {
    getToken(state) {
      return state.token;
    },
    getUserName(state) {
      return state.userName;
    },
    getPublicData(state) {
      return state.publicUserData;
    },
    getUser(state) {
      return state.user;
    },
    isAuthenticated(state) {
      if (state.token !== null && state.token !== undefined && state.token !== '') {
        return state.token;
      }

      if (cookies.get('token')) {
        return cookies.get('token');
      }
      return null;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken(state, payload) {
      state.token = payload.access_token;
      cookies.set('token', payload.access_token);
    },
    setUsername(state, payload) {
      state.userName = payload;
    },
    setUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
    },
    setPublicData(state, payload) {
      state.publicUserData = payload;
    },
    clearAuthKey(state) {
      cookies.remove("token")
      state.token = null
    }
  },
  actions: {
    logout(vuexContext) {
      vuexContext.commit("clearAuthKey");
    },
    async getUser({commit}, payload) {
      try {
        let response = await fetch(`${process.env.baseURL}/AuthServices/user`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "authenticated": "Bearer " + cookies.get('token'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          },
        }).then(res => res.json());
        if (response.status) {
         commit('setUser', response.data[0]);
        } else {
          await this.$router.push('/auth/login');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        await this.$router.push('/auth/login');
      }


    },
    async getUserNameForChatList({commit}, payload) {
      try {
        let response = await fetch(`${process.env.baseURL}/AuthServices/get-user-name-for-chat-list?`+new URLSearchParams({
          id: payload.id,
        }), {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            "authenticated": "Bearer " + cookies.get('token'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          },
        }).then(res => res.json());
        if (response.status) {
          commit('setUsername', response.data[0]);
        } else {
          await this.$router.push('/auth/login');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        await this.$router.push('/auth/login');
      }


    },
    async getPublicData({commit}, payload){
      try {
        let response = await fetch(`${process.env.baseURL}/AuthServices/user-public-data?`+new URLSearchParams({
          id: payload.id,
        }),{
          method : 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          },
        }).then(res => res.json());
        if(response.status){
          commit('setPublicData', response['data'][0]);
        }else{
          await this.$router.push('/');
        }


      }catch (e){
        await this.$router.push('/');
      }
    },
    async extractTokenFromRequest ({commit},req) {
      const cookiess = new Cookies(req.headers.cookie, { path: '/' });

      commit('setToken', cookiess.get('token') ?? '');
    },
  },
};
```